# Distance Calculation for massive number of devices/nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, distance

I have *N* mobile devices/nodes (say 100K) and I periodically obtain their location ( latitude , longtitude ) values.

Some of the devices are "logically connected" to roughly *M* other devices (say 10). 
My program periodically compares the distance between the each device and its logically connected devices and determines if the distance is within a threshold (say 100 meters).

I need a robust algorithm to calculate these distances to the logically connected devices.

The complexity order of brute force approach would be N*M  or  Θ(N2)

The program does this every 3 seconds (all devices are mobile), thus 100K*10 = 3M calculations every 3 seconds is not good.

Any good/classical algorithms for this operation ?

Comment: All N devices change every 3 seconds?

Comment: Well, are there any other assumptions that can be considered? Otherwise, if **every** logically connected pair is also `close enough`, then you have to do "brute force" in either case.

Comment: @odedsh Yes all N devices may change lat,long values by moving etc. They may also stay still but no assumptions here.

Comment: @barak Well they cant change lat,long values dramatically. I.e. no teleportation :) other then that no assumptions. An Example for logically connection would be: "My family" if the nodes are humans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(To simplify my explanation, I have omitted the detail about each device only being logically connected to M ~= 10 other devices.)

Spatially partition your device locations. If you are only interested in pairs of devices less than 100 meters apart, consider the following two algorithms.

1. For i = 1..N, j = 1..N, i != j, compute distance between devices i and j.
2. For i = 1..N, compute which grid cell the latitude and longitude for device i lies in, where grid cells are 100 meters square. Now for all nonempty grid cells, compare devices in that cell only with devices in the same cell or one of the eight adjacent cells.

   The data structure for this approach would basically be a map M from grid cell index (s,t) to list of devices in that grid cell.

The first approach is naive and will cost Θ(N<sup>2</sup>).  The second approach will, assuming there is some "constant maximum density of devices," be closer to Θ(N) in practice.  A 100 meter radius *is* fairly small.

The pseudocode for the second approach would look something like the following.

```
M = {}

for i = 1..N
  (s,t) = compute_grid_cell(i)
  if ((s,t) not in M)
    M[(s,t)] = []
  M[(s,t)].push(i)

for i = 1..N
  (s,t) = compute_grid_cell(i)
  for s' in [s-1, s, s+1]
    for t' in [t-1, t, t+1]
      if (s',t') in M
        for j in M[(s',t')]
          if i != j and distance(i, j) < 100
            report (i,j) as a pair of devices that are "close"
```

Comment: Nice idea. How would you address, if the distance for logical connection is also variable ? I.e. 100 meters between (A,B,C) and 500meters between (A,B,E,F,G). Sorry not to mention this earlier. I ll edit the question

Comment: let me ask that in another question then.

Comment: @math_law Go ahead and link to the follow up question so that they're connected.

Comment: @TimothyShields:How about a quadkey?

Comment: @Phpdna What is a quadkey?

Comment: Looks good to me. Small detail: your last `if` in your pseudocode should probably test for `i != j` as well.

Comment: @TimothyShields:Nevermind,I think I understand why you get accepted.

Comment: @TimothyShields:But the difference is only multiple for-loop vs. some trees query. I think a quadtree isn't so complex.

Comment: @TimothyShields:A quadkey is a key-hash string combination to itdentify a tile number in the subdivision of a map. It's a spatial index.

Comment: @TimothyShields  check out the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953186/distance-calculation-for-massive-number-of-devices-nodes-part-2

Answer (score 0):

You can use a quadtree or a morton curve. It's reduce the dimensions and make the solution easier.

Comment: When the radius of interest is known (100 meters) it doesn't really make sense to use a quadtree.

Comment: @TimothyShields:Can you elaborate?

Comment: In this application, the only question that ever needs to be answered is "Are devices i and j less than 100 meters apart?" A quadtree is a very versatile data structure and could absolutely be used here, but there is no motivation. A regular grid of 100 meter square cells (represented as a map from cell index to cell contents) is already optimal in terms of the required operations. A quadtree would just add unnecessary complexity.